# ArcGIS API for JavaScript won't add graphics to map

Tags: point, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, null, typeerror

```
var point = new Point(-49.9, 39.3)
var symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol('http://www.prww-weather.com/hurricane/icons/post-tropical-cyclone.png', 50, 50)
var graphic = new Graphic(point, symbol);
map.on("load", map.graphics.add(graphic));
```

These four lines of code use the ArcGIS API for JavaScript to add a point to the map. However, for some reason, the code doesn't work and I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null

Can anyone tell me why this is occurring and how to fix it?

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/44607448/820534

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heer The map is not yet loaded , it will throw this error, because there is no graphics property yet ,

also your code is wrong : you have to surround your code inside the call back function as below :

```
map.on("load", function() {
    map.graphics.add(graphic);
});
```

Adding [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xosmvhL8/4/)

Comment: When I use the code you've provided, the error isn't thrown anymore, but the point still doesn't show up on the map

Comment: it depend on the projection system , and spatial ref , it could be added , just show , console.log(map.graphics); adn see if it was added corectly

Comment: just done a test ; seems work perfct !!! here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xosmvhL8/4/)

Comment: The fiddle works fine, but if I change the basemap to `dark-gray`, the map doesn't work anymore. Why does it do that? Is it just a bug with that basemap?

Comment: It turns out that the fiddle uses ArcGIS API v3.8, which does not support the `dark-gray` basemap. Reverting to version 3.2 allows the basemap to work. Thank you all for your help! :)

Comment: Great , I didn't know about the non support of dark gray map on V3.8 
Awesome :)

Comment: The "terrain" and "dark-gray" options were added at v3.12. ~ https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#setbasemap